# I need to set default value of array of object reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am getting an array or an object from the backend what my task is to set the first index mean [0] to set in default value but when I set I am getting undefined you can see in code **userL** taking my array of an object but when I print **userle** it's showing **label: undefined value: undefined** or when I print **userL** I'm getting my array of object list

```
 const [userL, setUserL] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${DJANGO_SERVER_ADDRESS}/auth/analyst/`)
      .then((res) => {
        setUserL(res.data);
      })
      .then(
        (result) => {
        },
        (error) => {
        }
      );
  }, []);
  console.log("ena1", userL);
```

```
const [userle, setUserle] = useState(
   { value: userL[0].username,
    label: userL[0].username,
  });
  console.log("nnnnnnnnnuuuu",userle)
console.log('nnnnnnnnnnn',userL[0])
```

```
const handleSelectChangeL = (object, action) => {
    setIndex(userL[object.id]);
    setUserlevel(null);
    console.log("select check", object.label, action.name, index);
    let name = action.name;
    let value = object.value;

    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
```

```
           <Col lg={2}>
              <label for="user">
                <header>User</header>
              </label>
              <Select
                options={userL.map((data, index) => ({
                  value: data.username,
                  label: data.username,
                  id: index,
                }))}
                styles={styles2}
                value={userle}
                name="user"
                onChange={handleSelectChangeL}
                placeholder="User"
                theme={(theme) => ({
                  ...theme,
                  colors: {
                    ...theme.colors,
                    text: "black",
                    primary25: "#d6fdf7",
                    primary: "#0bb7a7",
                    primary50: "#d6fdf7",
                  },
                })}
              ></Select>
            </Col>
```

Comment: Please try to include a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible*** Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we've more context for what you are trying to do. What is `userL`? When and where are you trying to console log these values?

Comment: added right now

Comment: Am I reading this correctly, that `userL` is defined in the same component as `userle`? If so then OFC `userL[0]` will be undefined, it hasn't been populated yet. Use an `useEffect` hook to populate the `userle` state when `userL` updates, or just set it at the same time the `userL` state is being set.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the state of the userle from the first element of the data, do it this way.

```js
const [userle, setUserle] = useState()
const [userL, setUserL] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${DJANGO_SERVER_ADDRESS}/auth/analyst/`)
      .then((res) => {
        setUserL(res.data);
        setUserle(res.data[0]?.username);
      })
      .then(
        (result) => {
        },
        (error) => {
        }
      );
  }, []);
```

**EDIT**

To also update the userle state onChange of the dropdown list, add `setUserle()` under your `handleSelectChangeL` function.

**JS**

```js
const handleSelectChangeL = (object, action) => {
    setIndex(userL[object.id]);
    setUserlevel(null);
    console.log("select check", object.label, action.name, index);
    let name = action.name;
    let value = object.value;
    
    setUserle(value); // Add this line   

    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
```

Comment: ok but I need to set this defalt value in my dropdown list

Comment: @dev Okay, then please provide the `handleSelectChangeL` function. If you want to update the value of `userle` on the dropdown list.

Comment: ` const handleSelectChangeL = (object, action) => {
    setIndex(userL[object.id]);
    setUserlevel(null);
    console.log("select check", object.label, action.name, index);
    let name = action.name;
    let value = object.value;

    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  }; `

Comment: data is coming in my dropdown list only need to set first value and label in defalt

Answer (score -2):

if you using useState, You cannot get expected result of updated state in same function, but if want to print the result, you must write useEffect with dependency userle state or maybel you can console it above "return" statement in functional Commponent